# MySQL allows creating a table using JSON and traditional data types? Is it a good design

Tags: mysql, json, database-design, architecture, database-performance

In my project, I am creating table using traditional data types like `INT, VARCHAR` and mixing it with columns of `JSON` datatype. 
E.g Create table `EMP as EMPID INT, EMPProfile data JSON`.

What are the pros and cons of this approach?

I am inclined to use JSON as the data in it is very specific to the user. But there could some elements that are common across users.

E.g in the `EMP` Profile, the gender is generic but the Hobbies part is specific to the user. Need guidelines/suggestions. thanks

Comment: What will your queries look like?

Comment: the queries are to show EMP his profile and do some analytics on the common attributes across profile. E.g EMP between age 20-30 and Gender Male. I do not want to be restricted in how I use the data. And so raised this question.

Comment: Work up both the `CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT` -- with and without JSON.  That exercise will probably lead you to the answer.  If not, edit your question so we can help you debate the alternatives.